# Access attributes from the database

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database, authentication

In this database table (administration), there are 4 attributes (email, name, password and mobile phone). I need that inside the if I can use each one of them but I don't know how I can access them.

How can I do this?

```
private void button_login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String username, user_password;

    username = txt_username.Text;
    user_password = txt_password.Text;

    try
    {
        String query = "SELECT * FROM administracao WHERE email = '"+txt_username.Text+"' AND password = '"+txt_password.Text+"'";

        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(query, conn);
                
        DataTable dtable = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dtable);

        if (dtable.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            // username = txt_username.Text;
            // user_password = txt_password.Text;
                    
            /* Menuform form2 = new Menuform();
            form2.Show();
            this.Hide();*/
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid Login details", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);

            txt_username.Clear();
            txt_password.Clear();

            txt_username.Focus();
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error");
    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: **WARNING:** Your code is **dangerous**. It is wide open to SQL injection attacks. Always, *always, **always*** parametrise your code. [Why do we always prefer using parameters in SQL statements?](//stackoverflow.com/q/7505808) You are also storing plain text password, making the problem even worse. If someone entered their email address as `'; SELECT email, password FROM administracao; --` your **ENTIRE** user credentials could be exposed.

Comment: @Larnu this is just a project for the university, i'm not too worried about security. I really need to be able to access the values ​​of this user

Comment: If I were your university tutor, I would be severely docking your marks if you had such a huge well known and easily avoidable security flaw. Code right the first time.

Comment: @PedroGonçalves writing correct code is a *lot* easier than what you posted here

Comment: Besides, the purpose of this assignment is to learn and use the proper ADO.NET classes. You already loaded the data into a DataTable. Have you tried reading the rows and values?

Answer (score 0):

For communication with database I would strongly recommend **Entity Framework**.

In your case you can use **SqlDataReader** to get output data from sql query

**Code Example:**

```cs
public void GetData()
{
    var query = "your query";
    var connectionString = "your connection string";

    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        var command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
        connection.Open();

        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        try
        {
            // Iterate all selected rows
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                int value1 = (int)reader["Int column name"];
                string value2 = (string)reader["String column name"];
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            reader.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

**NOTE**:

1. In real project **NEVER** store passwords as plaintext. [How to do it properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054022/best-way-to-store-password-in-database)
2. As people already mentioned in the comments, when you decide to execute query directly from the code **NEVER** combine query like you did, because of [SQL Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601300/what-is-sql-injection). Use parametrized SqlCommands. [How to do it](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/a20beb/why-should-always-use-the-parameterized-query-to-avoid-sql-i/)